# W/System (10375): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

In flutter when I use firebase to signup or login a user it won't let the user switch to the other screen as you see in the code below it should allow the user to go to that page but it doesn't. It just keep loading. And this is the error I keep getting:

W/System  (10375): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.

```
   home: StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
                builder: (ctx, userSnapshot) {
                  if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
                    return NavigationScreen(
                      currentIndex: 1,
                    );
                  }
                  return AuthScreen();
                }),
```

And I know an account is created because when I restart the app it goes to the other screen and it also tells me this when it keeps loading:

```
 D/FirebaseAuth( 4303): Notifying id token listeners about user ( 2ab0Z7FcYlMr96lxbvBAPOfeLvk1 ).
D/FirebaseAuth( 4303): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( 2ab0Z7FcYlMr96lxbvBAPOfeLvk1 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

old question but incase someone else gets stuck:

Instead of :

> return NavigationScreen(currentIndex: 1,);

write out the code to push to a different page.
Like this:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> NavigationScreen(currentIndex: 1,)));
```